# How to retrieve a user firebase auth ID token in the new firebase version 9?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

How to retrieve a user firebase auth ID token in the new firebase version 9?

This is how it is done in firebase version 8 below

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
  // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle error
});
```

Does anyone know how it is done in firebase version 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getIdToken()` needs to be imported from the Auth SDK as shown below:

```
import { getAuth, getIdToken } from "firebase/auth"

const auth = getAuth();
const user = auth.currentUser

if (user) {
  getIdToken(user).then((token) => {
    console.log(token)
  })
}
```

The same goes for `getIdTokenResult()` to get user's custom claims.